# Python stdin and stdout and what is the advantage of using it?

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

Some explanation of the sys.stdin.isatty() in the context of this code would be very helpful. I know what this command does but I don't understand why we need it in this context.

```
import sys

class Redirection(object):
    def __init__(self, in_obj, out_obj):
            self.input = in_obj
            self.output = out_obj

    def read_line(self):
            res = self.input.readline()
            self.output.write(res)
            return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not sys.stdin.isatty():
            sys.stdin = Redirection(in_obj = sys.stdin, out_obj = sys.stdout)

    a = input('Enter a string: ')
    b = input('Enter another string: ')
    print('Entered strings are: ', repr(a), ' and ', repr(b))
```

What is the advantage of reading a file using stdin that reading a file with the help of "with open() as f" command.

And is there a way to modify this code so that it reads all the contents of the file.

Comment: Hint: Compare the output of this program, when run with input taken from a file, with the output of the lines-17-to-19-only program. (Except this program won't run at all, because read_line should be readline, so fix that first. :-) )

Comment: So when you say take input from the file, how do I do that. Do I run a command like the following on my terminal: python3 script.py | cat first.txt | cat second.txt

Comment: First put two lines of text into, say, test.txt. Then run python3 script.py <test.txt .

Comment: OK, great. So it takes two lines from a file. But what if there are more than two lines in the file.

Comment: The program only reads two lines; it ignores everything after the second line of input.

Comment: Is there a way to read all the contents of the file. And what is the advantage of using this method of reading a file than reading a file using the "with" command.

Comment: Now we're straying *really* far from the original question.

Comment: Yes, I got curious. Thanks for the help. And by the way I re-edited the question.